# Dropzone processQueue never finishes with AWS Upload + large number of files (>10)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, dropzone

A while back I converted a static file system uploader to work in conjunction with AWS S3. The existing uploader used dropzone and I found some suggested methods using the AWS managedUpload to do the upload via the AWS sdk when using dropzone.

It seemed to work fine, but now that we are trying to put it into production and running it through stress tests, I'm finding that the queue 'stalls' if you try to upload a large number of files.  I'm not sure what the problem is or how to go about fixing it.  It doesn't seem to be a fixed point where it stalls, but tends to do it for larger numbers of larger files (greater than 10 or more files - I generally test with from 20-30 to reproduce this issue and it will die anywhere from position 10-20 in the queue. Sometime it will even manage to complete so it's hard to find any specific issue causing it)

The dropzone definition in my uploader is as follows:

```
var dz = new Dropzone(
    selector.settings.listId,
    {
        url: "/",
        method: 'put',
        thumbnailWidth: 150,
        thumbnailHeight: 150,
        thumbnailMethod: 'contain',
        dictRemoveFileConfirmation: 'Are you sure?',
        acceptedFiles: "image/*,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif",
        autoQueue: true,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        params: {directory: selector.directory},
        clickable: [".ImageSelectorUploadButton"],
        previewTemplate: selector.settings.dropzoneTemplate,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            // todo add check on file itself to make sure it's a valid image
            selector.getAwsHelper().getAwsToken().then(function(data) {
                // options for the managed upload for this accepted file
                // define the bucket, and the S3 key the file will be stored as
                var fullKey = selector.getUtil().sanitize_path(selector.getAwsHelper().getUserFileKey(selector.settings.userId,selector.directory, file.name), true);
                var params = {
                    Bucket: selector.getAwsHelper().S3DefaultBucket,
                    Key: fullKey,
                    Body: file,
                    Region: selector.getAwsHelper().region,
                    ContentType: file.type // sets the file mime type when uploaded
                };
                // add an S3 managed upload instance to the file
                file.s3upload = selector.getAwsHelper().getManagedUpload({params: params});

                // support optional callback
                if (typeof(done) === 'function') done();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.error( {method:"ImageSelector::createDropzone",message:"Dropzone::accept file accept error"}, err ); // DEBUG
                vex.dialog.alert("Error retrieving AWS token")
            });
        },
        canceled: function(file) {
            if (file.s3upload) file.s3upload.abort();
        },
        init: function () {
            this.on('removedfile', function (file) {
                if (file.s3upload) file.s3upload.abort();
            });
        }
    }
);
```

The getManagedUpload() is just a simple wrapper to the browser S3 sdk client

```
getManagedUpload: function (options) {
    return new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload(options)
}
```

Anyone that can offer any suggestions or help to either stop dropzone from stalling or get it started again, it would be greatly appreciated.